# Dialog Box Positioning and Replacing X with Close

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

Am very new to JavaScript... Am using JQuery to create a custom dialog box.

Question(s):

1. How to position the dialog box to anywhere I want on the screen using specific (X,Y) coordinates (or some other mechanism)? Do not want it to appear in the middle.
2. How to replace the X with "Close"?

Have this but this just makes the dialog box's titlebar disappear:

```
function showBox() {
  $( "#showBox" ).dialog( 
       {
          closeOnEscape: false,    
          open: function(event, ui) {
              $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); 
       }
  );
}
```

1. How to set it so it can not be dragged or moved by the end user?

Any help would be most appreciated...

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 0):

1. [position](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-position) option
2. [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-draggable) option

You'll probably have to play around with the Close logic to get what you want but here's the gist of it...

```
function showBox() {
    $( "#showBox" ).dialog({
        open: function(event, ui) {
            jQuery('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').removeClass("ui-dialog-titlebar-close").html('<span>Close</span>');
        },
        draggable: false,
        position: [350,200],
        closeOnEscape: false
    });
}
```

Edit: sorry the links don't work, but those options are found under the options tab on the linked page.